# Advantages of servicesapicontroller over api controller

Tags: sitecore-api, sitecore-services-client

I've been looking for best way to expose a api that returns data in Sitecore and I found some implementation which use ServicesApiContorller, what are the advantages of using this controller over normal MVC webapi contoroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServicesApiController is just like a regular Web API controller +it was added benefits of the security and filter options which come the Sitecore.Service.Client.